# SimpleWorkerRequest.SendResponseFromMemory. Bytes read from WebClient.DownloadData do not match

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, webclient, simpleworkerrequest

I am trying to serialize an object and send it over the web.  I can serialize and immediately deserialize the object just fine.  However, when I try to send the bytes over HTTP using this on the server side:

```
byte[] b = ObjectToByteArray(anObject);
SimpleWorkerRequest.SendResponseFromMemory(b, b.Length);
```

and then use on the client side:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
byte[] result = client.DownloadData(url);
```

the result bytes do not match the byte b that was sent.  I have tried changing the encoding used, but it only changes the bytes around, they never match.  I did see that WebClient has an encoding field, but that is only for DownloadString.  What sort of encoding is used for client.DownloadData?  How can I ensure the bytes stay the same?  If there is an alternative to SimpleWorkerRequest that lets me send text, that would be awesome too..

**Edit:**
If I make an ASP.NET project and use

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",
                                 "attachment; filename=whatever.bin");
```

It works!  I tried to go back to the SimpleWorkerRequest and add:

```
swr.SendKnownResponseHeader(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest.HeaderContentType, "application/octet-stream");
```

But I am not sure about the other part.. if I browse to the page, it displays as text, not a download